# How do I align 3 separate drop down menus so they display side by side, horizontally?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Here is the link to my site,  [HighCountryCampingEquipmentAndOutdoorSports.com](http://HighCountryCampingEquipmentAndOutdoorSports.com)
The drop down menus are displayed like this:

------Hunting Equipment------
---Boating/Marine Navigation---
-----Search Tents by Size-----

But I want them side by side like this:

---Boating/Marine Navigation---  -----Hunting Equipment-----  -----Search Tents by Size-----

Here is a copy of the script I'm using:

```
<FORM name="guideform">
<SELECT name="guidelinks" onChange="window.location=document.guideform.guidelinks.options[document.guideform.guidelinks.selectedIndex].value"> <OPTION SELECTED value="jdrop2.htm">--Choose--
<OPTION value="jex15.htm">Page 1
<OPTION value="jex16.htm">My Cool Page
</SELECT>
</FORM>
```

Can anyone tell me, What the script code is that I need to add to the above script, to tell it to position the 3 pull down menus in a row, side by side like this:
  Menu A    Menu B    Menu C

---

Instead of:
      Menu A
                 Menu B
                 Menu C

I'm still learning and I don't know all the programming lingo", so could someone please give me an example script of how to do this?  I've searched all over the net for a couple weeks now, and I can't seem to find out how to do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why those three drop downs are under each other is that the 'form' element surrounding them is being rendered in 'block' style. You want these three 'form' elements to be 'inline' or 'inline-block'. The best solution is probably to add a css class to these elements with a "display: inline-block" style.

BTW...take a look at your rendered source code ('view source'). Run it through a validator. Here is a link:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://highcountrycampingequipmentandoutdoorsports.com/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

You may want to fix these errors. Quite a few non-standard html / compliance issues that may cause rendering issues.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

For HTML dropdowns, enclosing it in p tag. here's an example:

```
<form>
Select your favorite browser:
<p>
<select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser()">
  <option></option>
  <option>Google Chrome</option>
  <option>Firefox</option>  
  <option>Internet Explorer</option>
  <option>Safari</option>
  <option>Opera</option>
</select>
<select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser()">
  <option></option>
  <option>Google Chrome</option>
  <option>Firefox</option>  
  <option>Internet Explorer</option>
  <option>Safari</option>
  <option>Opera</option>
</select>
</p>
</form>
```